# Event handling for bound canvas WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, events, binding, canvas

I have a number of canvas bound to an observable collection. Each of which itself is bound to an observable collection of objects ([Binding-a-nested-list-to-a-wpf-canvas-panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974259/binding-a-nested-list-to-a-wpf-canvas-panel)).

My problem is that I cant seem to add event handlers to those canvas. I tried adding a PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event to both, the Canvas and the ItemControl, but both give a null reference exception even if the event is empty and I havent clicked the canvas.

Does this happen for a reason? Is there a way around it?

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you get the NullReferenceException? In the handler? While trying to bind the event?

Comment: Yes, I'm binding the event in the xaml code. As soon as I run the application I get a null exception.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code?

```
<Grid PreviewMouseDown="Grid_PreviewMouseDown">
            <Border Padding="5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red" CornerRadius="3"
                                Background="White">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </Border>
        </Grid>
```